# Have to Track the Campaign ID and Description using DataViews

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, ampscript, data-views, marketingcloudapi

Currently, I'm tracking the email sent details using data views and storing in a DE, I need to track campaign ID and Description in the same DE. Is there a way to track it using Data Views?

In my research, I got to know that this can be achieved only through API Call,

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/retrieving_an_email_via_the_soap_api.htm

But is there any other way to achieve this?

Thanks Inadvance